# How can I do to use a email service for a same domain on other server

Tags: email, hostname

For example, the server I am using uses the host name "A.com". Now, I want to send an email to "A@A.com". But the email server isn't on this server. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Unix. You need to set an MX record in DNS for `a.com`. This record points to the name of the host which handles the mail for this domain. If there is no MX record for the target domain then the host `a.com` itself is tried for delivery.

You can check that with `host -t A google.com` vs. `host -t MX google.com`.